# Django Tastypie: instancemethod object is not iterable

Tags: django, tastypie

Trying to add ToManyField to the resource. Here is the model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
...
def access_set(self):
    return User.objects.all()
```

Here is the resource:

```
class ProjectResource(ModelResource):
...
access = fields.ToManyField(UserResource, attribute = 'access_set', readonly=True, null=True)
...
```

I have the error: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable

Any thoughts please?

Comment: Don't know tastypie but it feels like it could be expecting access_set to be a @property.

Comment: @jbasko Thank you, that was the right answer...dunno what to do with question now?

Comment: Posted it as an answer so you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels like it could be expecting `access_set` to be a @property:

```
class Project(models.Model):

    ...

    @property
    def access_set(self):
        return User.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thank you, @property def access_set(self)... is the right solution =)